# I get the following error ExecJS::ProgramError in Posts#index How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, row

Here is a link to the image of my exact error:
  http://puu.sh/fHXJf/f714496a53.png

Here is the rest of my code that may be the issue

This is in my Gemsfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
```

This is in my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Blogsite2</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks- track' => true %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by downloading Node.js and installing it directly to my C: Drive!